# How to use boost::format to zeropad a number where the number of decimal places is contained in a variable?

Tags: c++, boost, zero-pad, boost-format

I would like to zeropad a number such that it has 5 digits and get it as a string.  This can be done with the following:

```
unsigned int theNumber = 10;
std::string theZeropaddedString = (boost::format("%05u") % theNumber).str();
```

However, I do not want to hardcode the number of digits (i.e. the 5 in "%05u").

How can I use boost::format, but specify the number of digits via a variable?

(i.e. put the number of digits in `unsigned int numberOfDigits = 5` and then use numberOfDigits with boost::format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can modify the formatter items using standard io manipulators:

```
int n = 5; // or something else

format fmt("%u");
fmt.modify_item(1, group(setw(n), setfill('0')));
```

With a given format, you can also add that inline:

```
std::cout << format("%u") % group(std::setw(n), std::setfill('0'), 42);
```

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99899029327942a4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/format/group.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, char const**) {
    std::cout << format("%u") % io::group(std::setw(argc-1), std::setfill('0'), 42);
}
```

Where it prints

```
0042
```

because it is invoked with 4 parameters

Comment: Thanks.  That's great.  I'll give it a little more time before I accept it as an answer because I'd like to see if other people might also have good answers.

Comment: Nice question and great answer. Wonder why there are so little votes.